# How do you hide the Address bar in Google Chrome for Chrome Apps?

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications

I want to increase the screen real estate for my Chrome app. The Address Bar is useless in a Chrome App and I was wondering if there was a way to disable it.

Comment: Only way I know to do so would be to enter full-screen mode.

Comment: `CMD+Shift+F` (not cmd+ctrl+f)

Answer (score 300, accepted):

You can run Chrome in application mode.

Windows:

```
Chrome.exe --app=https://google.com
```

Mac:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --app=https://google.com
```

Linux:

```
google-chrome --app=https://google.com
```

This removes all toolbars, not just the address bar, but it will definitely increase your real estate without having to use Kiosk mode.

Comment: You suggested the same thing that Stead did :) Unfortunately using F11 or "Full Screen" mode limits you to just that being in full screen mode. Application mode allows you to use the browser as normal without all of the (in this case) unnecessary toolbars and drop down menus.

Comment: i think your solution is more of a permanent fix for specific sites, where mine is more of a situational fix :)

Comment: For mac, you have to run /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --app=<url>

Comment: While using --app how to tell Chrome.exe to run as a single process (not making too many processes in alt+ctrl+del list? so that the CPU and Memory is used but cleaned up)

Comment: It's a shame they [dropped](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Chrome-dropping-compact-navigation) the [Compact Navigation](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-enable-new-compact-navigation-feature-in-google-chrome-make-toolbar-and-addressbar-auto-hidden/) feature early on.

Comment: Would anyone know how to do this on Android? I sometimes need to use Android Chrome in Desktop mode on a phone. In my cases the URL bar occupies too much real estate. Thank you!

Comment: this can also be used with `msedge.exe --app=https://google.com/`

Comment: Linux works also in android?

Answer (score 122):

Visit the site you want in Chrome.
Click the Chrome menu in your browser toolbar.

- Select "More Tools" > "Create shortcut…"
- Check "Open as window", press "Add"

Once you launch from that shortcut it will be a window without toolbar.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. No need to fiddle with shortcuts. **This is a built-in Chrome feature.**

Comment: on the current version of chrome on windows this is in menu > more tools > add to task bar + check open in window

Comment: @jopfre I have the last chrome version but I can't find 'add to task bar' option. Maybe you have an extension for that?

Comment: The new way (late 2015) on ChromeOS is "More Tools", "Add to shelf...", "Open as window" (checkbox). For Chrome browser, it is ... "Add to Applications..."

Comment: @Ovidiu Just tested in incognito and it's as I stated.  windows7  chrome v 47.0.2526.111 - just underneath save page as.

Comment: I can't find this feature for the Chrome browser on Mac OS. Anyone know if this is supported?

Comment: this answer is obsolete

Comment: Changed my answer to reflect new Chrome windows menu. And no, isn't obsolete.
Selected answer isn't the right way to do it. It will just enable fullscreen.

Comment: @Ovidiu it would be very helpful indeed and I d mark as right answer if built in feature, but I don't see the option you described in "more tools" menu. Version chrome 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit) on mac. Also tried to chrome://flags/#disable-hosted-apps-in-windows as in https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=224903 but does not appear

Comment: Is there a way to be able to open new tab links in full screen mode automatically too?

Comment: Seems obsolete as of  Chrome 60.0.3112.90 (at least on Mac), `More Tools" > "Add to Desktop"` is not offered.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  All other answers are overly complicated and involve unnecessary steps.

Comment: @WebelITAustralia-upvoter Is not obsolete.  Option is there in Chrome v64 (64b)

Comment: @JoelZA Thanks for checking. Still can't see it. Chrome 64.0.3282.186 
Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.5. https://www.webel.com.au/stackoverflow/chrome-menu-add-where.png (Might be specific to OS version. There might be another preference/setting to activate it I have overlooked.)

Comment: @JoelAZ it doesn't appear on mine either on 64.0.3282.186

Comment: @WebelITAustralia-upvoter and RayfenWindspear - that is odd.  I'm now on 65.0.3325.146 (official, 64b) on Windows 10 and option is definitely there.  Running any kind of extension?  Try a clean profile maybe?  Dunno.  I'd grab you a screencap but can't post it in comment.

Comment: Renamed to `Create shortcut...`. I'm Version 67.0.3396.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Dec 18 it's now "More Tools > Create Shortcut" then "Apps > Right click app > Open as Window".

Comment: Silly question: after the shortcut is created (still works in Chrome 72), where does it go?! Or is this different from a bookmark and doesn't actually get saved? In other words, can the shortcut simply be opened after I do this once, or do I need to recreate it every time?

Answer (score 44):

### Mac

- <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> goes fullscreen
- <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> hides the navbar
- also worth noting `...` → `More Tools` → `Create Shortcut...` creates a standalone Application, just make sure you're logged into the Chrome Profile you want to be active

---

### Windows

- <kbd>F11</kbd> (possibly <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> too)

Comment: Uh, it's possible the user simply wants to have the web page in a window with nothing but the page and the window frame (no address bar or tab bar). Entering full screen is not the answer then.

Comment: This shortcut appears to be broken in Chrome 46 (dev channel). Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: `CMD+Shift+F` will hide the navbar once you're in fullscreen mode

Comment: or ONLY when you're in full screen mode

Answer (score 10):

**Uncheck** `Always Show Toolbar in Full Screen` in `View` menu:

[image]

and go to fullscreen then:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> - on Mac

<kbd>F11</kbd> - on Windows

Comment: Super ! I just did some tutorial screencasts (using ScreenFlow on Mac) and it worked brilliantly using this Always Show Toolbar in Full Screen mode option. I *disabled* the toolbar as shown, and it displayed a Java web application perfectly for screen capture. Thanks !

Answer (score 8):

In the latest version of Chrome (Version 50.0.2661.94 m) you can accomplish this by going to the menu and then clicking -> More Tools -> Add to Desktop. You will then want to check off "Open as Window" in the popup that appears and then click "Add". Screen shots below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to be able to open new tab links in full screen mode automatically too?

Answer (score 6):

Hitting F11 may work for you.(Full-screen mode)

It appears that the hiding the address bar without going full screen is no longer an option:http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/d7LfleRNX7M

Answer (score 5):

On macs chrome browser:

#### 1st toggle on Full screen:

`cmd-ctrl-f`

#### 2nd toggle on hide address bar, tabs and all

Just repeat to undo or hover above top

`cmd-shift-f`

#### Undo by repeating backwards:

- `cmd-shift-f`  undo  hide
- `cmd-ctrl-f`   undo full screen

Answer (score 3):

2016-05-04-03:59A - Windows 7 - Google Chrome [Version 50.0.2661.94]

wanted this done for a 'YouTube Pop-out Player' without Chrome Address / Toolbar or Bookmarks Bar; solution ended up being a small edit of MarkHu's answer (because of new updates, i guess?)

Go to the page you want altered, select Chrome Toolbar's 'Hamburger button' (3 horizontal lines).

From there: **More tools > Add to desktop... > Open as window (tick box) > Add (button).**

... and, simply open your page from the new desktop shortcut, adjust as needed, and enjoy!

Comment: If you would like to know how to hide the YouTube search bar that appears at the top of the pop-out: Right-click and choose "Inspect element" to open the developer tools.  Locate "masthead-positioner" and press Delete twice.  Now you can size the screen so that only the video is visible!

Answer (score 1):

Even though the question is about gaining some space removing the address bar, you can also gain some space by toggling the bookmark bar on and off, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, or <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, in Mac OS.

Comment: Just commenting, since nobody actually cared to point why this is wrong: the OP was referring to the URL bar, not the favorites bar.

Comment: I believe this low rated answer was trying to help without giving the answer requested.

Answer (score 1):

Vivaldi Chromium-based Browser can hide the address bar for my Home Theather PC. Using that app you can show/hide a floating bar with F8 key.
Other answers are unrelated to what was asked!

Answer (score 0):

Instructions as of Dec 2018:

1. Visit the site you want in Chrome
2. From menu select "More tools" > "Create shortcut..."
3. From apps (can visit chrome://apps/), right click site then enable "Open as window"

Now when you open the shortcut it will open in a window without toolbar.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

in macOS
make service by automator.

that's it. you can assign short cut.

Answer (score -1):

For Chrome on Ubuntu (16.04), F11 is the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

to answer your question about how to hide the address bar I will suggest checking [blurscreen.app](https://www.blurscreen.app)

here is how it works

[image: hide address bar in chrome]

ps: you will not have more real state though