# How to hide address bar from chrome and mozilla

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I want to give demo to some person of my web application so i want to capture screen without Address bar so that they will not know the domain, can you please tell me how to hide address bar  or can i hide domain .  I have latest chrome and Mozilla

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F11 really maximise the window. But if you move your mouse (or presss any key), the navigation bar reappears, thus revealing the URL again !

For hiding URL

- Firefox: View -> Toolbars -> Untick "Navigation bar" Toolbar

Comment: Sadly it won't work on new v86. No option again for that ability. aaa...

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a self-written stylesheet to achieve that purpose for Firefox.

It hides the complete top-bar and appears when hovering over the top window-border, or focusing the address-bar with the key-combination `Ctrl+L`.

It's not perfect (e.g. there can be a flickering effect when focusing the address-bar, or after clicking the hamburger-symbol to open the menu, you need to use the Arrow-Down-key for selecting a menu-item) but works for me:

https://github.com/ida/skriptz/blob/dde60dadcca5bb45ce6ca14bb74373637f31a309/setup/browser/ff/userChrome.css

Comment: Just found a relating question and answers with the same approach on superuser, too: https://superuser.com/questions/977912/firefox-hide-everything-except-content-area-of-the-browser/1491728#1491728

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record and for defending my necromancer badge:

**For Firefox:** The addon ["Hide Navigation Bar"](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/hide-navigation-bar/reviews/) worked till version 52 came out. I don't know of any other method of hiding it.

To hide the Tabbar, the addon ["Hide Tabbar"](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/hide-tabbar/) should still work. I guess it will continue to work until November 2017, when [WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Add-ons/WebExtensions/What_are_WebExtensions) will be the big deal and probably break a lot of old addons like e.g. [TabGroups](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/tab-groups-panorama/). Just read the first few comments on the tab-groups addon page, to learn that not everyone is pleased with WebExtensions, and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Legacy_Firefox_for_Android) to learn that probably some legacy-addons are already defunct.

I'm no addon-developer, and don't know if the situation really is that dramatic, but I'll sure miss tab-groups.

**For Chrome:** User Force has given the ultimate hint [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124877/how-do-you-hide-the-address-bar-in-google-chrome-for-chrome-apps/20663518#20663518), for hiding everything except the content-area. I'll use it to watch amazon prime video.

Answer (score 0):

F11 hides the address bar in Firefox eventually. Using it a second time will make the bar reappear.

If you only want to *hide* the address bar, uncheck the menu item at *View* > *Toolbars* > *Navigation Toolbar*.

Comment: F11 is actually the button to make Firefox full screen, but I guess for his needs, it's adequate.

Comment: When giving a demo, you probably don't need the noise around your browser. I know it's not really a solution for your problem. But I would consider it a workaround.

If you really want to hide the address bar, you can select View > Toolbars > Navigation Toolbar (uncheck it)

Comment: relates to older version

Comment: @Thom: the question was asked in 2013 :) Do you know by any chance when it changed? :P

Comment: Maybe on version 60... didn't mean to downvote, sorry about that :) didn't see date posted at first.

Answer (score 0):

In firefox right click on toolbar and uncheck navigation bar, or go to view - > toolbars and uncheck navigation bar. In chrome full screen mode is solution (F11)