# Can javascript running on client under one profile open a new window under an alternate profile?

Tags: javascript, firefox

Can a script in a web page open a new window under a different profile if the profile name is known? I'm most interested in Firefox but would like to know about other browsers also.

I'm referring to something as discussed in the question [Open Chrome or Firefox without tabs and other menu items and with a set screen position and size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147233/open-chrome-or-firefox-without-tabs-and-other-menu-items-and-with-a-set-screen-p#26149547) at the bottom.

In that scenario, if Firefox was initially opened in no-remote, could the shortcut open the first html page under the default profile, and the script in that page open the second window under the alternate profile? Or, do both have to be under the same profile?

I'm asking because I'd like the first window to have the standard browser menu, tabs, etcetera, and have a button that opens a new full-size window under a profile that excludes all of that including the address bar, and that doesn't jump out of full-screen when the mouse position reaches the top.

The second window is to be a "work" window that runs an application and doesn't display a url.

Also, since the question I referenced is 3 yrs 8 months old, is there another way to accomplish this without extensions or add-ons?

If it is possible, I'd like to open the new page under the new profile in the existing window instead of a new window.

Thank you.

Comment: Would be terrible if JS running in the context of a normal website(?) could start any executables.

Comment: I didn't repeat the details of the question I referenced and the scenario it presented, but probably should have.  It's not referring to a normal website, but a local html page.